# Incremental Cooperative Rebalancing leads to unevenly balanced connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We encounter lots of unevenly balanced connectors on our setup since the upgrade to Kafka 2.3 (also with Kafka connect 2.3) that should include the new Incremental Cooperative Rebalancing in Kafka connect explained here : 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-415%3A+Incremental+Cooperative+Rebalancing+in+Kafka+Connect

Let me explain a bit our setup, we are deploying multiple Kafka connect clusters to dump Kafka topic on HDFS. A single connect cluster is spawned for each hdfs-connector, meaning that at any times, exactly one connector is running on a connect cluster. Those clusters are deployed on top of Kubernetes with randomly selected ips in a private poll.

Let's take an example. For this hdfs connector, we spawned a connect cluster with 20 workers. 40 tasks should run on this cluster, so we could expect to have 2 tasks per worker. But as shown in the command below, while querying the connect API after a while, the connector seems really unbalanced, some workers are even not working at all while one of them took ownership of 28 tasks.

```sh
bash-4.2$ curl localhost:8083/connectors/connector-name/status|jq '.tasks[] | .worker_id' | sort |uniq -c
  ...
      1 "192.168.32.53:8083"
      1 "192.168.33.209:8083"
      1 "192.168.34.228:8083"
      1 "192.168.34.46:8083"
      1 "192.168.36.118:8083"
      1 "192.168.42.89:8083"
      1 "192.168.44.190:8083"
     28 "192.168.44.223:8083"
      1 "192.168.51.19:8083"
      1 "192.168.57.151:8083"
      1 "192.168.58.29:8083"
      1 "192.168.58.74:8083"
      1 "192.168.63.102:8083"
```

Here we would expect that the whole poll of workers are used and the connector evenly balanced after a while. We would expect to have somethings like :

```sh
bash-4.2$ curl localhost:8083/connectors/connector-name/status|jq '.tasks[] | .worker_id' | sort |uniq -c
  ...
      2 "192.168.32.185:8083"
      2 "192.168.32.53:8083"
      2 "192.168.32.83:8083"
      2 "192.168.33.209:8083"
      2 "192.168.34.228:8083"
      2 "192.168.34.46:8083"
      2 "192.168.36.118:8083"
      2 "192.168.38.0:8083"
      2 "192.168.42.252:8083"
      2 "192.168.42.89:8083"
      2 "192.168.43.23:8083"
      2 "192.168.44.190:8083"
      2 "192.168.49.219:8083"
      2 "192.168.51.19:8083"
      2 "192.168.55.15:8083"
      2 "192.168.57.151:8083"
      2 "192.168.58.29:8083"
      2 "192.168.58.74:8083"
      2 "192.168.59.249:8083"
      2 "192.168.63.102:8083"
```

The second result was actually achieved by manually killing some workers, and a bit of luck (we didn't found a proper way to force an even balance across the connect cluster for now, it's more a process of try and fail until the connector is evenly balanced.

Does anyone already came across this issue and manage to solve it properly ?

Comment: It seems that with the older protocol, the issue is not happening. Not a real solution but it may do the trick, waiting for a real solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348308/how-to-get-kafka-connect-to-balance-tasks-connectors-evenly

Comment: Here is the JIRA for the bug
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10413