# How to get Kafka Connect to balance tasks/connectors evenly?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I trying to run a Kafka Connect distributed cluster with 5 workers and 2 sink connectors. One connector is configured with max.tasks and actual tasks set to 5. The other connector is configured for 6 tasks.

If I understand things correctly this should mean 13 "work units" (1 connector + 5 tasks + 1 connector + 6 tasks) that need to be distributed to the workers. Which i figured would mean around 2-3 tasks/connectors per worker.

However, I'm finding that the eventual assignments are as follows:

```
Worker 0: (3 Work Units)
   - Connector 0
   - Connector 1 Task 0
   - Connector 1 Task 1

Worker 1: ( 4 Work units)
   - Connector 1
   - Connector 0 Task 0
   - Connector 0 Task 2
   - Connector 1 Task 3

Worker 2: (2 Work units)
   - Connector 0 Task 3
   - Connector 0 Task 4

Worker 3: (4 Work units)
   - Connector 0 Task 1
   - Connector 1 Task 2
   - Connector 1 Task 4
   - Connector 1 Task 5

Worker 4: ( 0 Work Units)
```

I'm using Kafka Connect workers running 2.6.0 and a connector built against 2.6.0 libraries. Workers are deployed as containers in an orchestration system (Nomad) and have gone through several rounds of rolling restarts/reallocations but the balance always seems off.

Based on this I'm finding myself at a loss for the following:

- I'd get that tasks may get a bit unbalanced while restarting or moving containers but i'd expect once the last one came up and joined the cluster a final balancing would have sorted things out. Can some one point me to why this might not be happening?
- Is there a recommended way to trigger a rebalancing for the whole cluster? From the docs it seems that changing config for a connector or a worker failing/joining might cause a rebalance but that does not seem to be an ideal process.
- Can the task balancing process be configured or controlled in anyway?

Comment: can you also tell us what connector(s) are you using?

Comment: @BogdanSucaciu it is a custom s3 sink connector we built. Similar to the one here https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud but also tries to preserve message keys in addition to some configurable limits to avoid OOMing when having to sink a large # of partitions.

Comment: Message keys can be preserved via `transforms` feature and memory limits are set with JVM settings outside of connect, so I don't see a need to build your own

Comment: Transforms could work but seemed off considering the sink connectors get the record, with key, anyway. Also for log compacted topics I found it useful to have the key to avoid an ever increasing bucket.

Yes the limits are configured for the worker. But since there appears to be no way to control the # of tasks a worker is assigned I'm trying to keep things resilient to these balancing instances by keeping task resource requirements predictable. In any case I was under the impression that connect doesn't really consider the connector implementation when balancing tasks at all.

Comment: is it always that Worker 4 gets no assigned tasks? does it have the same `group.id` like the others? Also, can you try out a few things to maybe isolate a bit more the issue? Try using a different connector type with the same configuration ( same number of connector instances / tasks ) and observe if the tasks are properly balanced. Do you have any insights from monitoring? While rebalancing all the workers have enough resources to respond promptly?

Comment: i haven't seen anything interesting from monitoring but will try turning up the logging level and see if anything shows up. The `group.id` is the same for all workers (i can query the status from Worker4's rest endpoint just fine).

I _think_ there are enough resources to handle the tasks in general (though the imbalance causes problems since a worker can only handle so many tasks..). So I am very curious about how a task and/or worker should provide feedback to ensure healthy operation.

Comment: I've found I can avoid this situation by using the older protocol (setting  `connect.protocol=eager`). The best I could gather is that for some reason the reassignment didn't trigger with revocation as expected which would have gone through the balancing.

Comment: There is a jira issue about unbalanced task assignment when using new default cooperative rebalance protocol https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10413